# JavaScript mouseover and mouseleave event

Tags: javascript, mouseover, mouseleave

I have a `mouseover` and `mouseleave` event listener on the same elements, when you `mouseover` it adds a class and `mouseleave` removes the class.

I am running a `forEach` so that when you `mouseover` a specific item it shows a specific block of text for that item. That's why I'm using JS and not plain CSS.

I was looking for a way to optimize the following piece of code, please.

```
const pageNavRings = document.querySelectorAll('.page-nav-ring')

pageNavRings.forEach((pageRing) => {
  pageRing.addEventListener('mouseover', (e) => {
    const pageRingParent = e.target.closest('.page-nav__list--item')
    pageRingParent.querySelector('.page-nav-label').classList.add('is-visible')
  })

  pageRing.addEventListener('mouseleave', (e) => {
    const pageRingParent = e.target.closest('.page-nav__list--item')
    pageRingParent.querySelector('.page-nav-label').classList.remove('is-visible')
  })
})
```

Seems like this piece of code can be written better and more **DRY**. All and any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: `classList` has a `toggle` method that might help...

Comment: More code is less code. Declare the functions instead of creating a ton of similar functions in a loop. Check also if it's possible to reduce event listeners by using event delegation.

Answer (score 1):

My attempt to make it more compact and clear. Not sure about your html, so used `parentElement` to get label.

```
    const rings = document.querySelectorAll('.page-nav-ring')

    rings.forEach((ring) => {
        const label = ring.parentElement.querySelector('.page-nav-label');
        ring.addEventListener('mouseover', () => { label.classList.add("is-visible") });
        ring.addEventListener('mouseleave', () => { label.classList.remove("is-visible") });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd solve this without using JavaScript but CSS:

```css
.page-nav-ring > .page-nav__list--item {
   opacity: 1;
}
.page-nav-ring > .page-nav__list--item:hover {
   opacity: 0.1;
}
```

```html
<ul class="page-nav-ring">
  <li class="page-nav__list--item">Hello World</li>
  <li class="page-nav__list--item">Hello World 2</li>
  <li class="page-nav__list--item">Hello World 3</li>
</ul>
```

No more JS needed. Of course you can change the `opacity` attribute to the attributes you need.

Comment: I'm doing a `forEach` on the elements, so when you `mouseover` it shows a specific block of text for that specific item. That's why I used JS

Comment: and how should we know this? please update your question with the relevant code...

Comment: `it shows a specific block of text` still not there

Answer (score 0):

```
const pageNavRings = document.querySelectorAll('.page-nav-ring')

pageNavRings.forEach(pageRing => {
  // Move everything into `handler` function
  // to make use of scoping (you will see why later)
  pageRing.addEventListener('mouseover', handler);
})

function handler(e){
  // Cache these values using variable
  const className = 'is-visible';
  const pageRingParent = e.target.closest('.page-nav__list--item')
  const pageRingLabel = pageRingParent.querySelector('.page-nav-label');

  pageRingLabel.classList.add(className);

  // Add `mouseleave` event listener in this handler is fine
  // Because it doesn't need to listen to this event
  // before everything started anyway
  this.addEventListener('mouseleave', e => {
    // Using the values from the const above,
    // You don't have to use `e.target.closest` and `querySelector` again
    pageRingLabel.classList.remove(className);
  });
}
```